# how to add array to existing json localstorage element?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I am using the below code to a**dd a key-value pair to the existing localStorage object root element.**

But it is not adding a new pair after root element. not in existing element.

```
  var students = []
  var student1 = { 'rank': this.getAttributeValueById(this.product.rank, 'rank') }
  var kkey = 'shop/elasticCache/sku$$' + this.product.parentSku
  students.push(student1)
  var old = []
  old = localStorage.getItem(kkey)
  localStorage.setItem(kkey, old + JSON.stringify(student1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have described only occours becuase the
"old + JSON.stringify(student1)" is not doing what you expect

What you want to do is something like

```
var student1 = { 'rank': this.getAttributeValueById(this.product.rank, 'rank') }
var updatedList = [...localStorage.getItem(kkey), student1]
localStorage.setItem(kkey, JSON.stringify(updatedList))
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, let me check

Comment: but this will override whole existing object with 'rank'

Comment: Will throw error if nothing in that storage key. Also what is stored is a string , not array